# Composite Graph SOQL Support

Tags: soql, rest-api, composite-graph

I can't find an example of executing SOQL using the Composite Graph API. My request body

```
{
    "graphs": [
        {
            "graphId": "graph1",
            "compositeRequest": [
                {
                    "url": "/services/data/v51.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+RecordType+WHERE+SobjectType+=+'Account'+AND+DeveloperName+=+'PersonAccount'+LIMIT+1",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "referenceId": "personAccountRecordType"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Response

```
{
    "graphs": [
        {
            "graphId": "graph1",
            "graphResponse": {
                "compositeResponse": [
                    {
                        "body": [
                            {
                                "errorCode": "OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED",
                                "message": "Endpoint not supported in Composite Graph API: /v53.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+RecordType+WHERE+SobjectType+='Account'+AND+DeveloperName+=+'PersonAccount'+LIMIT+1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "httpHeaders": {},
                        "httpStatusCode": 404,
                        "referenceId": "personAccountRecordType"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "isSuccessful": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite Graph API only supports few types of API. The query API is not supported.

[image]

The docs are [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_graph_introduction.htm).

For the other different types, I recommend a move to regular REST API.